# NetworkError: 500 Internal Server Error

Tags: php, internal-server-error

When I try to execute this file, it show me black page..

i start the firebug it shows me that NetworkError: 500 Internal Server Error
i tried to solve but cant find any problem here..

so could you help me to find what is the error or problem..??

```
class DesEncryptor
{
protected $_key;
protected $_iv;
protected $_blocksize = 8;
protected $_encrypt;
protected $_cipher;

/**
 * Creates a symmetric Data Encryption Standard (DES) encryptor object
 * with the specified key and initialization vector.
 *
 * @param $key
 * @param $iv
 * @param bool $encrypt
 */
public function __construct($key, $iv, $encrypt = true)
{
    $this->_key = $key;
    $this->_iv = $iv;
    $this->_encrypt = $encrypt;

    $this->_cipher = mcrypt_module_open(MCRYPT_DES, '', MCRYPT_MODE_CBC, '');
    mcrypt_generic_init($this->_cipher, $this->_key, $this->_iv);
}

public function __destruct()
{
    mcrypt_generic_deinit($this->_cipher);
    mcrypt_module_close($this->_cipher);
}

/**
 * Transforms the specified region of the specified byte array using PCKS7 padding.
 * @param $text
 * @return string
 */
public function transformFinalBlock($text)
{
    if ($this->_encrypt)
    {
        $padding = $this->_blocksize - strlen($text) % $this->_blocksize;
        $text .= str_repeat(pack('C', $padding), $padding);
    }

    $text = $this->transformBlock($text);

    if (!$this->_encrypt)
    {
        $padding = array_values(unpack('C', substr($text, -1)))[0];
        $text = substr($text, 0, strlen($text) - $padding);
    }

    return $text;
}

/**
 * Transforms the specified region of the specified byte array.
 * @param $text
 * @return string
 */
public function transformBlock($text)
{
    if ($this->_encrypt)
    {
        return mcrypt_generic($this->_cipher, $text);
    }
    else
    {
        return mdecrypt_generic($this->_cipher, $text);
    }
}
}
```

When i debug with var_dump(), i found that in function transformFinalBlock

```
$padding = array_values(unpack('C', substr($text, -1)))[0];
```

it throw me error like " '[' is unexpected "

Guys, solutions plz...

Comment: enable display of http error message first.

Comment: How do you use this class? A class definition does not do anything by itself!

Comment: @ShivanRaptor it shows nothing in mozilla, but in IE error shown like syntax error, unexpected '[' in line ----- $padding = array_values(unpack('C', substr($text, -1)))[0];

Comment: @Mohsenme i include this file in my index.php file & use the function of this file..

Comment: Can you run other scripts? Do you have .htaccess file (server configuration file) in your directory?

Comment: @user3181866 learn PHP please. show error by adding `ini_set('display_errors', '1');` in the first line as well as reading this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11749043/php-not-displaying-errors-internal-server-error-500

Comment: @ShivanRaptor i said i already did that what you said me, i told also that it not displayed in mozilla but in IE it show me error & what error i got that i also wrote here.. Look at that...

Comment: @Mohsenme nothing that i use.. i just want to run my index file & want to use the function of this.. nothing more.. & what error i got that i also described here..

Comment: i got the error in following line 
$padding = array_values(unpack('C', substr($text, -1)))[0];
may be i have to write like
$padding = array_values(unpack('C', substr($text, -1)));
$padding = $padding[0];

Comment: What is the exact error you got ? click the magic **edit** button & update your question please.

Comment: What php version do you have installed?

Comment: It's a shorthand array syntax, your php version should be >= `5.4.0`, to get it work.

Comment: @Daedalus Apache Version :
    2.2.21  
PHP Version :
    5.3.8

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Array de-referencing, which is what you are doing with the line `$padding = array_values(unpack('C', substr($text, -1)))[0];`, is only possible as of [php 5.4](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php#example-89), any prior versions, you will have to do the following to access your array:

```
$arr = array_values(unpack('C', substr($text, -1)));
$padding = $arr[0];
```